# Variable not updating inside requestJS's data event

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, scoping

I am trying to cache response from a url to a variable and send it on subsequent request. For this I am writing to variable on data event of request. The variable is updated but I am not able to access it out of the event's callback.

Below is the code and log I generated out of it.

I am not able to understand why despite getting updated in `data` event callback it's length is 0 in `end` event callback.

Note : `data` variable has url attribute, `req` and `res` request and response variables.

```
var cache = {} ; //global variable
function get_from_box_cached (data,req,res){
   var options = _.extend({}, REQUEST_OPTIONS, {url : data.url, method: req.method}) ;

   if (cache[data.url]){
       console.log(data.url + "available in cache");
       res.send(cache[data.url]);
   }else{
       cache[data.url] ="";
       var request_to_server = request(options);
       request_to_server.on('data', function(data){
           cache[data.url] += data.toString('ascii');
           console.log("data event : cached : " + cache[data.url].length);

       });
       request_to_server.on('end', function(){
           console.log("end event : cached : " + cache[data.url].length);
       });
   }
}
```

Log :

```
data event : cached : 8201
data event : cached : 8556
data event : cached : 16393
data event : cached : 17548
data event : cached : 24585
data event : cached : 32777
data event : cached : 40969
data event : cached : 49161
data event : cached : 57353
data event : cached : 65545
data event : cached : 73737
data event : cached : 81929
data event : cached : 90121
data event : cached : 98313
data event : cached : 102941
end event : cached : 0
```

Calling code :

```
app = require('express)();
app.all('/abc/*',function (req, res) {
    var data = {};
    data.url  = SERVER_URL + "/" + url.parse(req.url).path;
    get_from_box(data,req,res);
});
```

Comment: in the log is the lowest entry the first or the last one time-wise? how exactly is your `cache` variable created? it seems that `cache` gets out of scope before the (asynchronous) request ends.

Comment: lowest one is the last one time-wise as it is printed last.
Cache variable is global or at least I intend to keep it global. 
I do not understand how does it go out of scope before request ends, can you elaborate?

Comment: Your request is asynchronous, so this means that the `get_from_box_cached` function can return before the request is finished. Maybe `cache` gets out of scope (cleared) and/or somehow re-declared in the meantime?

Comment: ok!! I missed that. But then how do I achieve what I want to achieve. i.e Caching ? How do I store the response into the variable and persist ?

Comment: did you try to create the variable globally in your main script (i.e. the one that you start with the `node` command)? if you want a persistent cache, you need to save to disk somehow... there is the npm pacakge [node-localstorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-localstorage) to mimic client-side local storage on the server for variable caching.

Comment: `var cache = {}` and this function is wriitten in main script. I dont want to persist across multiple runs and the problem is I am not able to understand why doesn't it prints proper length in`end event`. I am sure `end event` occurs after the `data events`

Comment: how does your function get called?

Comment: Have you tried isolating your code? What does your `request()` function do? What other functions access the `cache` variable? To check if the variable really is registered as global, you can try `console.log(global.cache);`. If it prints `undefined`, then your variable wasn't registered as global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple cache object module, that way you don't pollute the `global` object and it may help for debugging purposes, i.e. you can print some info each time the data is changed (make sure to only change the data property using the `append`/`clear` methods, not directly).

e.g. **cache.js:**

```
module.exports = {
    data: [],
    append: function(url, data) {
        if (!this.data[url]) { this.data[url] = ''; } // initialize
        this.data[url] += data;
        console.log('cache[' + url + '] length:', this.data[url].length);
    },
    clear: function(url) {
        if (url) {
            delete this.data[url];
            console.log('removed', url, 'from cache');
        }
        else {
            this.data = [];
            console.log('cleared cache');
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your main script:

```
var cache = require('./cache');

request_to_server.on('data', function(data) {
    cache.append(data.url, data.toString('ascii'));
}
```

You can also `require()` the module in any other script and it will keep its data, because that is how modules work in Node.js.

Comment: Thanks ... I found another solution. I used [cached-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cached-request) package.

It uses file system to cache request.